# Rails. wrong number of arguments error when trying to set beginning_of_week

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, activesupport

I followed this Railscast: http://railscasts.com/episodes/213-calendars-revised

It seems that not a lot of people are getting an error but I get `ArgumentError: wrong number of arguments (1 for 0)` for this call:

```
first = date.beginning_of_month.beginning_of_week(START_DAY)
```

Even, if I try it in the console it also gives me the same error.

```
Date.today.beginning_of_month.beginning_of_week(start_day = :sunday)
Date.today.beginning_of_month.beginning_of_week(start_day = 'sunday')
Date.today.beginning_of_month.beginning_of_week('sunday')
Date.today.beginning_of_month.beginning_of_week(:sunday)
```

I already Googled it and looked in the docs and it seems it should just work. I even tried `require 'active_support/all` but it always returns `false`.

How can I set the beginning of week as Sunday?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I cant access the screencast. But when i run Rails in Console mode (not IRB):

rails c (Ruby v1.9.3p194)

```
Loading development environment (Rails 3.2.8)
1.9.3p194 :001 > Date.today.beginning_of_month.beginning_of_week(start_day = :sunday)
 => Sun, 29 Jul 2012 
1.9.3p194 :002 >
```

Maybe its your Ruby or Rails version, i'm running: rails (3.2.8)?

The parameter (what day the week starts) seems to be added since 3.2.1:

http://apidock.com/rails/v3.2.1/Date/beginning_of_week

Comment: and what does 'Date.today.beginning_of_month.beginning_of_week' do?